# Не получается добавить элемент DataGridView на форму C#

Tags: c#

Не получается добавить элемент DataGridView на форму C#, что делать и как быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте прямо в разметку руками

Comment: через разметку тоже не хочет(

Comment: что значит `не хочет`? Будьте конкретны

Comment: Это значит "Не удалось найти тип "DataDridView". Убедитесь, что не пропущена ссылка на сборку и что все сборки, на которые заданы ссылки, выполнены." using System.Windows.Forms; - присутствует.

Comment: я верно понял, вы пытаетесь положить WinForms элемент в WPF приложение?

Comment: Да, а так нельзя делать?(

Comment: нет, просто положить нельзя. Можно закинуть компонент, вроде называется WindowFormsHost или типа того и в него уже ложить ваш датагрид. Но я бы посоветовал решить вашу задачу обычными WPF контролами. WinForms контролы в WPF используют только в крайнем случае.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!